# Why AlertDialog suddenly disappeared and shows up again after pushing the back button?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a button that calls two method in a time. That is the alarm() and sms().
When i click on the button, the AlertDialog shows up but then disappeared  before I push the "STOP" button. Soon after it disappeared, i receive the sms. The AlertDialog shows up again if i push the back button. It seems i had a crash or something.

**The onCreate() method :**

```
btnAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAlarm);
        btnAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alarm();
                sms();

            }
        });
```

**The alarm() method :**

```
public void alarm()
    {
        Alarm1 = MediaPlayer.create(MySetting.this, R.raw.lingcoll);

        //Turn on the alarm sound
        Alarm1.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        Alarm1.start();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MySetting.this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.alert_stop)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_alert)
            .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_warning)
            .setCancelable( false )
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_btnStop, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                    Alarm1.stop();
                    MySetting.isAlarm = false;

                }
            });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        }
```

**The sms() method :**

```
public void sms() 
    {   

        TextView a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);

            String phoneNo = a.getText().toString();

            String message = "My Application works!";

                    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, FinalSetting.class), 0);                
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, pi, null);


    }
```

The LogCat seems fine so i dont know whats the problem.
Does anyone know how to prevent this???
Thanks so much for the advance..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is a context switch somewhere. Either your setting your contextView somewhere or something is crashing.

I'm thinking that your just setting the contextView somewhere because you Dialog is still alive in the stack when you hit back. Also make sure that your dismissing your Dialog onclick.

Lastly, You may need to check that the variables your using in the dialog onclick need to be final. Eclipse usually catches this, but it could cause a crash.